# How to use intellij/grails and wslite soap client through a proxy like Fiddler to see the messages?

Tags: grails, soap, proxy

I want to setup a proxy inspection tool such as fiddler or Charles proxy (I have both), so I can see what is being sent and received - without this you are blind.

The question is, how to i tell grails 2.4.4 or the wslite-0.7.2.0 plugin to use my local proxy server?

Sadly, there is only 1 page of documentation for the plugin, with examples which are completely different to the groovy-wslite library it is supposed to bring in.

e.g. https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

says I should be able to do this:

```
 def proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress('proxy.example.com', 8080))
 def client = new SOAPClient("https://www.example.com/ExampleService")
 def response = client.send(proxy:proxy) {
```

But when I try this format, I just get:

```
 No signature of method: wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send() is applicable for argument types: (java.net.Proxy,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
        def client = new SOAPClient('https://bla')
        def proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress('localhost', 8888))
        client.httpClient.proxy = proxy

        def response = client.send(SOAPAction: 'blabla') {
```